# conditional probability on the sum of two random variables

Tags: probability, convolution

If I have $ X=Y+Z $ and $Y$ and $Z$ are independent, what is the high-level formula for finding $p(y|x)$? 
I was able to find the $p(X)$ using convolution but I am a little lost afterward wrt which formula should I use? Like in normal case (not a sum of two independent random variables) I know I should use $\frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)}$ however in this case, not sure what is the proper formula.

Comment: The Jacobian formula or simple common sense tells that $$p_{X,Y}(x,y)=p_Z(x-y)p_Y(y)$$ hence $$p_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)=\frac{p_Z(x-y)p_Y(y)}{p_X(x)}$$ where one knows that $$p_X(x)=\int p_Y(t)p_Z(x-t)dt$$